Proof that a base 2 logarithm of a rational number is irrational
How can I prove that if
$a = \log_2 b, b \in \Bbb Q, b \neq 2^c$ and $c \in \Bbb Z$
then
$a \notin \Bbb Q$ ?
And could the proof be easily adapted to differently-based logarithms?
I am familiar with proofs of the irrationality of square roots, but I don’t get how to prove this one.
I have worked out that $c \in \Bbb Z$ is an unnecessary condition because any rational but not integer $c$ would give an irrational $b$, which is already ruled out.

If $r=p/q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1,$ and $n=2^{p/q}$ for some $n,$ then $n^q=2^p.$ Then use unique factorization.

It works mostly the same for other integer bases that are not a perfect power. Obviously, $\log_4 8=\frac32,$ so to deal with a base which is a perfect power requires some care.

If $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ and $n=p_1^{b_1}\cdots p_k^{b_k}$ are the prime factorizations, then $\log_m n$ is rational if and only if $\frac{b_i}{a_i}$ is the same for all $i.$

@Thomas Andrews You must allow newbies like us to answer this! Just kidding (+1)

@ThomasAndrews thanks! What is “i” in your last comment though?

For all $i=1,\dots,k,$ specifically. @fedsavi
